# Consultar datos de una tabla MS Access y guardar los datos en una variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 foreach ($arrayCambiosMS as $key => $value) {
            $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido="SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='$value'";
            $ejecMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido);
            $datosToInsertMySQL=odbc_fetch_row($ejecMS);
            // $resultadoToInsertMySQL=odbc_result($datosToInsertMySQL);
        }

        echo $datosToInsertMySQL;
```

Realmente ya casi lo tengo pero estoy fallando en algo y no sé el qué. Así como está, el resultado que obtengo es un "1" y si descomento la última línea del código éste es el error que recibo:

```
Warning: odbc_result() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
```

Básicamente, para que comprendáis la lógica, arrayCambiosMS es un array dónde tengo varios IdPedido y con la consulta lo que quiero sacar es todos los campos de cada registro IdPedido de la tabla de MSAccess. Luego esa variable intermedia (ese array con todos los datos) lo insertaré en MySQL. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usa `odbc_fetch_array()`** para no tener que usar `odbc_result()`.

El problema real está en la lógica, porque parece que quieres obtener más de un registro, pero estás sobrescribiendo la variable `$datosToInsertMySQL` en cada iteración y haciendo echo solo al salir.

Así como lo tienes, puedes usar la variable dentro del ciclo, pero recuerda que `odbc_fetch_array()` te va a devolver un arreglo y con `echo` solo mostraría algo como *Array*.

```
 foreach ($arrayCambiosMS as $key => $value) {
        $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido="SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='$value'";
        $ejecMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido);
        $datosToInsertMySQL = odbc_fetch_array($ejecMS);
        // Mostrar lo que se obtuvo
        var_dump($datosToInsertMySQL);
        // Aquí mismo puedes realizar la inserción de este registro en MySQL
    }
```

Ahora, si prefieres acumular todos los registros para insertarlos posteriormente, necesitas crear un arreglo:

```
// Definir arreglo
$datosToInsertMySQL = [];
foreach ($arrayCambiosMS as $key => $value) {
        $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido="SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='$value'";
        $ejecMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido);
        // Agregar registro al arreglo
        $datosToInsertMySQL[] = odbc_fetch_array($ejecMS);
    }

// Recorrer para insertar
foreach($datosToInsertMySQL as $datos) {
    // Aquí insertas el registro en MySQL
}
```

Comment: `odbc_result()` se necesita para leer lo que trae la consulta. Es una particularidad curiosa de `odbc`, pero es así. Lo puedes leer en el Manual (enlace de mi respuesta).

Comment: @A.Cedano, tienes toda la razón, me quedé con la idea de que funcionaría igual que el resto de funciones  `*fetch_row()`, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 1):

La advertencia es clara: *`odbc_result() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`* indica que `odbc_result()` espera 2 parámetros y le estás pasando solamente uno. El uso de `odbc_result()` está claramente explicado en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-result.php).

Además de eso, viendo que tu código ocurre dentro de un bucle `foreach`, tu variable `$resultadoToInsertMySQL` guardará solamente el último resultado encontrado. Si quieres que se guarden todos los resultados que se encuentren dentro del `foreach` deberás declarar esa variable como array y usarla como tal.

Tu código podría quedar corregido así:

```
$resultadoToInsertMySQL=array();
foreach ($arrayCambiosMS as $key => $value) {
        $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido="SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='$value'";
        $ejecMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido);
        $datosToInsertMySQL=odbc_fetch_row($ejecMS);
        /*
           1. Ponemos [] para ir llenando un array con los resultados
           2. Ponemos el segundo parámetro a odbc_result 
              Como indica el Manual (ver enlace arriba) puedes poner
              el número de la columna o el nombre
        */
        $resultadoToInsertMySQL[]=odbc_result($datosToInsertMySQL,1);
}

print_r($resultadoToInsertMySQL);
```

### Recomendación

Podrías obtener todas las filas en una sola consulta (omitiendo el bucle `foreach` y una ejecución de `query` por cada valor de array, si construyeses una lista separada por comas con cada valor y la pasaras como criterio `WHERE IdPedido IN ( ... aquí la lista ...) ...`, para más detalles sobre el uso de `WHERE IN()` puedes consultar [la documentación de SQL Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/in-operator-microsoft-access-sql).